# Probability of having the sequence (H,H,T) as a part of a 6 time coin flip.

Tags: probability-theory

How can I calculate the probability of having the sequence (H,H,T) as a part of a 6 time coin flip?

H - stands for heads.
T - stands for tails.

I know that $\left|\varOmega\right|=2^{6}$, and I know that possibly, if I look at this 3-tuple, I can arrange it in 4 different indexes on the general 6-tuple, then I have 3 more "open spots" which can have 2 results.

So I computed $P(A)=\frac{\left|A\right|}{\left|\varOmega\right|}=\frac{2^{3}\cdot2^{2}}{2^{6}}=\frac{2^{5}}{2^{6}}=\frac{1}{2}$ where A is the wanted probability.

However, this isn't the right answer, because I count some events twice. How can I calculate this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only outcome you are counting twice is HHTHHT. So $P(A) = \frac{2^5-1}{2^6}$.

To see this, note that the possibilities are as shown in the following table:

$$
\begin{array}{rcccccc}
1)&H&H&T&*&*&*\\\
2)&*&H&H&T&*&*\\
3)&*&*&H&H&T&*\\
4)&*&*&*&H&H&T
\end{array}
$$

Clearly you can't fit another HHT in rows 2) and 3) and there is exactly one way of inserting another HHT into row 1) and row 4). So if you count the possibilities as $4\cdot 2^3$ you have counted HHTHHT twice.

Comment: Is there a safer way to compute this?

Comment: I don't know about "safer". I have tried to make the answer more explicit.

Comment: @GoodWilly This is essentially using the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion on the Indicator Variables $I_i = $ positions $i, i+1, i+2$ are $HHT$. Then $P(I_1 \cup I_2 \cup I_3 \cup I_4 = \sum P(I_i) - \sum P(I_{i} \cap I_j) + \ldots $, and notice that the intersection of 2 terms is 0 except for $I_1 \cap I_4$. This approach generalizes (but might be trickier for sequences like HTH).